# asp:RangeValidator on DateTime with format dd/MMM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

Is it possible to use the ASP.Net Range validator when the format string is dd/MMM/yyyy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use Regular Expression validator?

Comment: I highly recommend this method, and this is something I personally do.  The only problem, however, is that it will validate against a range of values per date segment.  Unless your regex skills are quite good you can't counteract for February.

Answer (score 0):

No. I think it should be a valid date (without the formatting)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net auto detects the culture info of the client. This info is used to resolve formatting like dates, currency etc.

You can override this with code (something like):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Or globally in the web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Of course this could have negative/positive side effects on the rest of your application, as it would affect other numbers/dates, but perhaps this is your intent anyway.